# unique relation between two columns X and Y using R

Tags: r

Is there anyway to get unique relation between two columns X and Y using R.
I need to check if two way relationship exist between X and Y and eliminate if rows if present.

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B" ,"C","E","F","G" ), Y =  c("E"  ,"F",   "G" ,"A","B","C") )

> df
  X Y
1 A E
2 B F
3 C G
4 E A
5 F B
6 G C
```

I want to get output as below

```
 > X Y
   A E
   B F
   C G
```

Comment: the length of  rows in my actual data frame is  variable.

Comment: `df.sort = t(apply(df, 1, sort))` `df[!duplicated(df.sort),]`